# "Error: Your android platform does not have Api.js" when trying to build android version 5.x.x

Tags: android, cordova, android-4.1-jelly-bean

cordova version is `7.0.1`

node version is `v8.0.0`

when running `cordova platform add android@5` everything works fine. (except for `cordova-plugin-media` requiring android version `>=6.1.0` but thats another story)

When running `cordova platform add android@4` (similar for `cordova platform add android@3`) I get

```
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@4
Adding android project...
Error: Your android platform does not have Api.js
```

despite cordova officially still supporting those android versions. What am I missing here?

The only other post remotely containing this particular error I found is [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-platform-add-android-error-your-android-platform-does-not-have-api-js/89272), but it was not helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem trying 6.0.0 version

```
npm install -g cordova@6.0.0
```

then there was error with bplist-parser in npm

```
npm install -g bplist-parser
```

All works fine!

Comment: So the newer version of cordova does not support android kit kat?

Comment: Yes, does not support

Comment: This worked for me, npm install -g cordova@6.0.0 . Thanks.

Comment: This is a kind of old solution and not working anymore.